# python return relative parent directory

Tags: python, relative-path, return-type

I run scripts from a cloud directory from several computers so for various reasons need to access the relative path to save outputs in other various relative paths. I expected the following script to return the root of the cloud directory but instead it returns a none-type. Can anyone help me understand why?

```
def get_relative_path(base_folder_name, current_path):
     import os

     parent = os.path.split(current_path)[0]
     print base_folder_name, os.path.split(current_path)[1]
     print type(base_folder_name), type(os.path.split(current_path)[1])

     if os.path.split(current_path)[1] == base_folder_name:
          return current_path
     else:
          get_relative_path(base_folder_name, parent)

import os
path = os.getcwd()
x = get_relative_path('cloud_folder', path)
print type(x)
```

the script returns:

```
cloud_folder child_folder
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
cloud_folder cloud_folder
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
<type 'NoneType'>
```

I expected it to return a string with the relative path to the cloud folder. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if os.path.split(current_path)[1] == base_folder_name:
      return current_path
 else:
      return get_relative_path(base_folder_name, parent)
```

you need to return the else case as well